# Detect scroll inside a non-scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scroll

How can I detect scroll inside a div with fixed height and no scroll? The following won't work:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper { height: 600px; }
```

JS:

```
$('.wrapper').scroll(function() { //... });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `onwheel` event:

```js
$('.wrapper').on('wheel', function() {
  console.log("Scrolled!")
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 680px;
  width: 150px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```